# House advantage if you allow retry

Tags: probability, gambling

Imagine you have a gambling game with a house advantage of $1\%$. The game is very simple, you flip a coin and you win or lose. Odds of either is $50\%$. If you win, you get $1.98$ times your bet.

Now what would it do to the house advantage, if the player is allowed to flip the coin again if he loses? For example, a player bets $\$10$, flips a coin, loses, flips again (for free), and could win. What is the house advantage in this scenario if such rule would apply?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You get better responses if you show your own attempts.

Comment: Probability is a number between 0 and 1. Thus, 50% wouldn't be odds. The odds would be 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what is the chance the player wins?  He need to win one flip of two.

Comment: I really don't know that's why I ask

Comment: The house has to win twice in a row.  What are the odds the player loses the first bet?  Assuming the player loses the first, what are the chances he loses the second.  Because you need A and B, which are independent you ....?

Comment: The probability of winning is that of getting a head on the first flip **or** the second flip (which requires a tail on the first flip). Out of all possibilities of two flips, how likely is it the person wins?

Comment: probability the player wins/loses the first bet is 50%
probability the player wins/loses the second bet is 50%

Comment: But the player doesn't lose unless s/he flips tails twice in a row, no?

Comment: That is correct.  To have both happen, you have a probability of $12$ on the first flip and again on the second, so the chance of the house winning both is $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12$  Have you seen this principle?

Comment: Yes so, 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4 or 25% chance the house wins over 2 hands; how do get the house edge of this?

Comment: So $\frac 14$ of the time the house wins ???  The other $\frac 34$ the player wins ???  The expectation for the house is then ???  The house edge is this divided by the stake.

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate that. Is it -1.25%?

Comment: No.  If the player were paid even money (so nets 1 when he wins) his expectation would be $\frac 34 \cdot 1 + \frac 14 (-1)=\frac 12$ or a $50\%$ edge-he wins $\frac 12$ for every $1$ bet.  This player is a little worse off.

Comment: No, a 50% probability he wins. I want to know about the house advantage of the casino under the conditions I outlined. 1% where the house pays out 1.98x on win.

Comment: The player has $\frac 34=75\%$ chance to win.  I said his advantage is about $50\%$, which means the house edge is about $-50\%$  It is a little less than that because the payoff is smaller.  The house edge is the house expected profit divided by the amount bet.

Answer (score 0):

The return when the player wins is $R(W)=-0.98$ (a loss for the house).  The return when the player looses is $R(L) = +1.00$ (a win for the house).

House advantage is the expected return for the house.  $\operatorname{E}_X[R(X)]$, where $X$ is the result of a game.

In the one flip game the expected return is:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{E}_X[R(X)] & = R(W) \Pr(W)+R(L) \Pr(L) \\ ~ & = (-0.98)(0.5) + (1.00)(0.5) \\ ~ & = +0.01\end{align}$$

In the two flip game the player looses if they loose two flips of the coin, the player wins otherwise.  This gives:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{E}_Y[R(Y)] & = R(W) \Pr(W_1 \cup (L_1\cap W_2)) + R(L) \Pr(L_1\cap L_2)\end{align}$$ 
Here $W_n$ is the event of a win on flip $n$, $L_n$ is the event of a loss.